# add_submenu_page как передать параметр в function

Tags: php, wordpress

Как передать параметр в `function` находящейся в `add_submenu_page`

```html
    add_submenu_page(
        'parent_slug',
        'page_title',
        'menu_title',
        'capabiliti',
        'menu_slug',
        'function'// Передать параметр сюда
    );
```

Допустим в `add_settings_field` можно передать параметры функции `callback`

```html
    add_settings_field(
        'id',
        'title',
        'callback',
        'page',
        'section',
        array( 'id' => 'count_1', 'option' => 'services_options' )// Вот так мы можем передать параметры в функцию callback
    );
```

Да и вообще, в php/wordpress есть способ передавать параметры любой функции, принимаемой в качестве аргумента?

Comment: Мда... беда... ну ладно, сделайте это ответом, я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Никак.
2. Нет никакого общего способа передачи параметров в вызываемую функцию. В ответе на прошлый вопрос я показал, как вызывается функция обратного вызова. Параметры ей передаются "вручную". Вот как сделали разработчики WordPress, так и работает. В одну функцию callback они предусмотрели передачу параметров, а в другую - не сочли нужным.